# How to simulate keys for game control in python

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes, opencv3.0, keyboard-events

I am trying to control a game Hill climb racing using python. I am using the code from this answer [How to simulate keys in game with pywinauto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660685/how-to-simulate-keys-in-game-with-pywinauto/43648717#43648717). But my system is not recognizing scan codes for the left arrow(0x4B) and right arrow keys(0x4D). Instead, it is recognizing these as pressing numbers 4 and 6. I couldn't find any alternate scan codes. Can someone please help me with this? I am using windows 10.

Comment: Do you have the NUMLK on?

Comment: Can't believe that was the issue!!! Thanks!!

Comment: Speaking from experience, you aren't the first nor will you be the last that has been snagged by the simple stuff