# pyautogui moves the courser but does not write in the function

Tags: python, pyautogui

The function `P_10` is supposed randomly select a path from the dictionary `Pic_10` and write it to `pic_loc`. Then the function `py_auto` is supposed to move the mouse cursor windows, explore the address bar, then write in the path to the folder.

It moves the cursor to the address bar but does not write anything.

Why is this code not working?

```
import pyautogui
import random
a = 287
b = 60
def py_auto():
    pyautogui.moveTo(a,b, duration = 1)
    pyautogui.click(a,b)
    pyautogui.write(pic_loc)

pic_loc =r""

Ovs_a_325 = r"D:\HOUSE PICS\10 marla\3F Ovs a ext @325"
OVB_8_425 = r"D:\HOUSE PICS\10 marla\8 overseas b @425"
ovb_40a_330 = r"D:\HOUSE PICS\10 marla"
tulip_47_350 =r"D:\HOUSE PICS\10 marla\47-c tulip @ 350"

Pic_10 = {
    1:Ovs_a_325,
    2:OVB_8_425,
    3:ovb_40a_330,
    4:tulip_47_350}
def P_10():
    global pic_loc
    pic_loc = random.choice(list(Pic_10.values()))
P_10()
py_auto()
```

[image: for some reason pyautogui.write(pic_loc) is blue]

Comment: added pic for some reason pyautogui.write() is blue instead of yellow

Comment: I'm not sure if this is related, but check out [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40619304/python-simulating-enter-keypress-in-a-game/65275819#65275819). Also, try running as Admin if you can