# How to simulate a key press in Python on a linux machine

Tags: linux, python-3.x

How do you simulate a key press in python on a linux machine?

This is for use with an emulator and making a bot which can play a game.

So primarily the 'wasd' keys, space and so on, this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489013/simulate-python-keypresses-for-controlling-a-game) is more or less what I want, however I believe that this solution is windows specific using

```
ctypes.windll
```

I believe that the main problem and why this is hard to do is to do with 'ScanCodes' and 'VKs', games tend to ignore as this is not how the user interacts with the game

So is there any linux workaround like the above for linux? 
Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem when using `pyautogui`. I just seemed to not have the right focus. Selecting the window in a few different ways did not help. Using `xdo` however, I managed to get the desired result.

Example:

```
from xdo import Xdo

xdo = Xdo()
win_id = xdo.get_active_window()
print(xdo.get_window_name(win_id))
xdo.send_keysequence_window(win_id, "Return")
```

More information:
https://github.com/rshk/python-libxdo

Comment: Corrected it: **`from xdo import Xdo`**
Also, keep in mind to `pip3 install python-libxdo`