# how to send a keyboard keystroke to active window?

Tags: python-3.x, winapi

I want to send a keyboard keystroke to active window, for example key A or Backspace using python. How can I do this?

I know active window coordinates as well (if it can help).

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922) and the [ask] section.

Answer (score -2):

The Windows API method to do this is [SendInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx) which is part of the User32 library. It sends keyboard and mouse input to the foreground/active window. SendInput uses the INPUT structure, specifically called KEYBDINPUT. It has the option of sending more than one INPUT because the first parameter details that:

nInputs [in]

```
Type: UINT
The number of structures in the pInputs array.
```

An example of using SendInput in Python is specified in the answer on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23468236/6095677).

You use the [MapVirtualKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646306(v=vs.85).aspx) function to map a virtual key code to a scan code

Comment: [You can’t simulate keyboard input with (Post|Send)Message](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513)

Comment: **SendInput** - yet, correct answer. **SendMessage** shouldn't really be discussed, unless it's in the context of sending a WM_CHAR or WM_KEYDOWN/WM_KEYUP message to a window. But those types of hacks just cause more trouble... since not all windows respondto input the same way.  I'd recommend adjusting your answer to just speak of the SendInput function.