# Simulate key presses in Age of Empires 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboard, pyautogui

I've been trying to make a simple python script that will send keystrokes to the game Age of Empires 3. I've tried pyautogui as well as using ScanCodes to do DirectInput, but nothing seems to work I just don't understand what kind of input the game needs or how its avoiding getting any inputs from my code. My codes kind of a mess from me testing several different methods, but here it is if anyone wants to see it.

```
import pyautogui
import pyperclip
import random
import keyboard
import time
from directkeys import PressKey, W, A, S, D


def spawn_hotdog():
    command = "mustard relish and burning oil"
    pyperclip.copy(command)
    pyautogui.click(500, 500)
    pyautogui.keyDown('enter')
    pyautogui.hotkey("ctrlleft", "v")
    pyautogui.keyDown('enter')


loop = False

while True:
    try:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('h'):
            loop = True
        elif keyboard.is_pressed('p'):
            loop = False
        elif keyboard.is_pressed('esc'):
            break
    except:
        pass
    if loop:
        time.sleep(1)
        PressKey(W)
        PressKey(0x1C)
```

and here is the directkeys.py file which I got from https://pythonprogramming.net/direct-input-game-python-plays-gta-v/

```
# direct inputs
# source to this solution and code:
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489013/simulate-python-keypresses-for-controlling-a-game
# http://www.gamespp.com/directx/directInputKeyboardScanCodes.html

import ctypes
import time

SendInput = ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput


W = 0x11
A = 0x1E
S = 0x1F
D = 0x20

# C struct redefinitions
PUL = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ulong)
class KeyBdInput(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("wVk", ctypes.c_ushort),
                ("wScan", ctypes.c_ushort),
                ("dwFlags", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("time", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("dwExtraInfo", PUL)]

class HardwareInput(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("uMsg", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("wParamL", ctypes.c_short),
                ("wParamH", ctypes.c_ushort)]

class MouseInput(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("dx", ctypes.c_long),
                ("dy", ctypes.c_long),
                ("mouseData", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("dwFlags", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("time",ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("dwExtraInfo", PUL)]

class Input_I(ctypes.Union):
    _fields_ = [("ki", KeyBdInput),
                 ("mi", MouseInput),
                 ("hi", HardwareInput)]

class Input(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("type", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("ii", Input_I)]

# Actuals Functions

def PressKey(hexKeyCode):
    extra = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
    ii_ = Input_I()
    ii_.ki = KeyBdInput( 0, hexKeyCode, 0x0008, 0, ctypes.pointer(extra) )
    x = Input( ctypes.c_ulong(1), ii_ )
    ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput(1, ctypes.pointer(x), ctypes.sizeof(x))

def ReleaseKey(hexKeyCode):
    extra = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
    ii_ = Input_I()
    ii_.ki = KeyBdInput( 0, hexKeyCode, 0x0008 | 0x0002, 0, 
ctypes.pointer(extra) )
    x = Input( ctypes.c_ulong(1), ii_ )
    ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput(1, ctypes.pointer(x), ctypes.sizeof(x))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    PressKey(0x11)
    time.sleep(1)
    ReleaseKey(0x11)
    time.sleep(1)`enter code here`
```

Comment: PyAutoGUI has trouble working in DirectX windows, which many Windows video games use. I'm afraid this might not be possible.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that your code was really buggy that's why it didn't work. I fixed some bug and it works. try to add some keystroke that enables the code.

```
import pyautogui
import random
import keyboard
import time

def spawn_hotdog():
    time.sleep(5)
    command = "mustard relish and burning oil"#command to type
    pyperclip.copy(command)
    pyautogui.click(500, 500)
    pyautogui.keyDown('enter')
    pyautogui.typewrite(command,interval = 0.10)
    pyautogui.keyUp('enter')#your code was buggy here
#types command in five seconds
spawn_hotdog()

#types command every five seconds
while True:
    spawn_hotdog()
    #add condition to break here!

#the rest of your code doesnt make sense
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but the rest of the code that I had was my attempts to make this work as what you have here is my original version of my code but without my methods of initiating it. The problem I was running into is pyautogui and pyperclip don't work with a game like Age of Empires due it being in DirectX.

Comment: I think you should try using PyUserInput I think that may work. https://github.com/PyUserInput/PyUserInput