# How do I make python copy and paste into a certain application using a keystroke?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyperclip

I am trying to make a piece of code that makes something like this

```
words = "hello my name is Leo"
```

Into this

[image: hello my name is Leo printed on separate lines on apple notes]

This is printed on apple notes but what I want it to do is to copy a the word of the text and paste it, then press the enter key and type another word.

Currently I have this

```
import pyperclip
words = "hello my name is Leo"

split = words.split()

for x in range(0,len(split)):
    pyperclip.copy(split[x])
```

I am not sure how to make it press enter (with a keystroke) and be able to use automate it to do it in another application. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you're looking for the newline character. To "press enter" use `\n` that will tell it to go to a new line.

You could really do something like

`words = "hello\nmy\nname\nis\n"`

Using the newline character would also eliminate the need for the for loop you used.

**EDIT:**

To simulate the keystrokes, use `pyautogui` library, that will work.
See: [Simulate key presses in Age of Empires 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52842667/simulate-key-presses-in-age-of-empires-3)

Comment: I'd need to not to do a new line but actually try and press the enter key because it is for something else I have been programming and newline won't do that unfortunately

Comment: @LeoGaunt try using the pyautogui library to simulate key strokes
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52842667/simulate-key-presses-in-age-of-empires-3

Comment: perfect, that was what I needed

Comment: I edited the post to have the solution, please accept the answer

Comment: Was going to ask you to do that anyway- thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Split your text by space then join it with `"\n"` characters. Then you can copy and paste it with `pyperclip`:

```
import pyperclip
words = "hello my name is Leo"
edited_text = "\n".join(words.split())
pyperclip.copy(edited_text)
...
pyperclip.paste()
```

Comment: I'd need to not to do a new line but actually try and press the enter key because it is for something else I have been programming and newline won't do that unfortunately

Comment: I admit the wording was slightly ambiguous but by press enter I meant a keystroke