# Direct Input in Euro Truck Simulator not working

Tags: python, directinput

I'm trying to create autonomous truck in Euro Truck Simulator 2, using PIL for image capture, OpenCV for image processing and tensorflow for action prediction.

The only problem is I am not able to send input to Euro Truck Simulator 2 game.
I am using Windows 10, capturing in 1280x720 windowed mode. Using Win32 Direct Input API as described below

 
[Stackoverflow Answer implementation of Direct Input in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23468236/11142523)

I am using PressKey function for W (0x11 Code) key and sleeping execution for 5 secs and then ReleaseKey to release the key.

The truck just won't move, the window is in focus while the script is running and also I can manually drive the truck as usual

```
PressKey(0x11)
time.sleep(5)
ReleaseKey(0x11)
time.sleep(1)
```

Note: I have also tried using pyautogui. Looping 50 times and pressing the key each time

Answer (score 0):

I know the solution to the problem. You can solve this problem with pydirectinput and pyautogui library.

[You can visit to see more information about it](https://pypi.org/project/PyDirectInput/)

```
import pyautogui
import pydirectinput
pydirectinput.keyDown('w')
time.sleep(5)
pydirectinput.keyUp('w')
```