# How would i go about simulating direct input to an inactive window?

Tags: python, input, keyboard, pywin32, simulate

I want to send direct input to a (possibly) inactive window in python.
So far i have found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489013/simulate-python-keypresses-for-controlling-a-game) to send direct input via ctypes and i have a solution to simulate input to a window, which doesn't work with some games as the one i am testing with (GTA V) is using direct input, using `postMessage()`via [py32win](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/).

So how would i now go about simulating those direct inputs while the target window is possibly not active? Is this even possible?

I would think it should be, because AutoHotkey for example can manage to send direct in such a case.

If you would like to experiment yourself i can provide the postMessage() version, otherwise i would like to keep the question code-free.

Comment: I'm not an expert on these things, but I think they would be accomplished through `win32gui`, `win32con` modules right? I know you can find handles for windows like `hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, 'GTA V')` or something similar, and would imagine that once you have the window handle you could just send keys to it? IDK I've never done it before

Comment: Well that's my problem. I technically got it working the way you said but since GTA V in this case for example expects direct input , it just ignores the keystrokes that are being sent to it via ```postMessage(hwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, wparam, lparam)```
Thus i am looking for a way to simulate direct input, which it expects

Comment: Oh I see so this is the same problem I ran into trying to do a project. I'll try (again) to solve it for the both of us :)

Comment: So you are saying that the game requires scan codes like shown at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489013/simulate-python-keypresses-for-controlling-a-game and you have already implemented a solution like this that works for an *active* window and just need to figure a method to send them to an inactive window?

Comment: Thats correct. I'd like to send those direct inputs to a specific window.
Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell you cannot do this. A workaround (found at https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/5wpxtt/automation_in_inactiveunfocused_window/) would be

- get a VM on your machine
- load the game and your script onto the VM
- run game and have your script interact with active window (on VM)
- minimize the VM window of your main machine

Comment: Mh yes, maybe there is no way to do it. However thats a good workaround you found, unfortunately i believe it's not practical to use because a VM is just too slow for such a game, especially since i would want to actually play when the bot is not active :D Have an upvote

Comment: @DJSchaffner I'll take it :)