# How to send DirectInput keys to an inactive window in Python

Tags: python, ctypes, pywin32

I would like to send DirectInput keys to an inactive window without interfering with my actual mouse. I tried using PostMessage, SendInput and SendMessage but pywin32 uses virtual keycodes while ctypes does work with DirectInput. I have no idea how I can make it send in an inactive window.

Comment: [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Can you post your code to get an idea what's working and what's not?

Comment: I have no code, I don't know how I can do this.

Comment: Hmm, then some statements are misleading: "*I tried using PostMessage, SendInput and SendMessage but pywin32 uses virtual keycodes while ctypes does work*".

Comment: Well, I did write that code, but it does nothing related to *directinput* it uses vk

Comment: Then, you'd better post it here in order to reduce the chances of getting this question closed. Check [\[SO\]: How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or
[\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
for more asking related details. Otherwise you'll get lots of *-1* s.

Answer (score -1):

Try using this, it manages to work for me send the keystrokes to the inactive window,

Use (but add error checking) hwndMain = win32gui.FindWindow("notepad", "​prueba.txt: log keys") hwndEdit = win32gui.FindWindowEx

Comment: I know how to send keys to an inactive window, I just want to send DirectInput keys to an inactive window

Comment: Try this post  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55387230/how-would-i-go-about-simulating-direct-input-to-an-inactive-window

Comment: I have seen that post, but I do not want to use that workaround.