# How do I send simulated keystroke to steam games on Windows 10?

Tags: c, python-3.x, windows, keypress, steam

I want to create a simple game controller/bot inside of a steam game similar to the one done [here on gtaV](https://pythonprogramming.net/direct-input-game-python-plays-gta-v/) to try out machine learning techniques. I've tried everything from pyautogui package, pyinput, and [this go to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489013/simulate-python-keypresses-for-controlling-a-game) method that was also used in the previous link and all of them work on the desktop apps and browsers but none of them work once I start the game.

I've also tried making and compiling this [C code](https://batchloaf.wordpress.com/2012/04/17/simulating-a-keystroke-in-win32-c-or-c-using-sendinput/) that I'm guessing the python is wrapping around but it's the same issue where it works until I enter the game screen.

I'm guessing the issue is something with the method of input as in the previous case, it had to be changed from ScanCodes instead of VKs but I have no idea on how to even figure out which input method must be used.

My current setup is python3 on windows10 home edition.