# Direct Input command not working while making gamebot

Tags: python, machine-learning, ctypes, directinput, scancodes

I've been working on automating GTA V with python. 
To give inputs, I tried "pyautogui" but it wasn't working as expected. I googled and got this solution on stackoverflow (and thank you, Sentdex!):

[Simulate Python keypresses for controlling a game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489013/simulate-python-keypresses-for-controlling-a-game)

I used the solution given by 'Hodka', made a few changes (just like sentdex) and here's my following code..

```
import ctypes
import time

SendInput = ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput

w = 0x11

# C struct redefinitions
PUL = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ulong)
class KeyBdInput(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("wVk", ctypes.c_ushort),
                ("wScan", ctypes.c_ushort),
                ("dwFlags", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("time", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("dwExtraInfo", PUL)]

class HardwareInput(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("uMsg", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("wParamL", ctypes.c_short),
                ("wParamH", ctypes.c_ushort)]

class MouseInput(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("dx", ctypes.c_long),
                ("dy", ctypes.c_long),
                ("mouseData", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("dwFlags", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("time",ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("dwExtraInfo", PUL)]

class Input_I(ctypes.Union):
    _fields_ = [("ki", KeyBdInput),
                 ("mi", MouseInput),
                 ("hi", HardwareInput)]

class Input(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("type", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("ii", Input_I)]

# Actuals Functions

def PressKey(hexKeyCode):
    extra = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
    ii_ = Input_I()
    ii_.ki = KeyBdInput( 0, hexKeyCode, 0x0008, 0, ctypes.pointer(extra) )
    x = Input( ctypes.c_ulong(1), ii_ )
    ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput(1, ctypes.pointer(x), ctypes.sizeof(x))

def ReleaseKey(hexKeyCode):
    extra = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
    ii_ = Input_I()
    ii_.ki = KeyBdInput( 0, hexKeyCode, 0x0008 | 0x0002, 0, ctypes.pointer(extra) )
    x = Input( ctypes.c_ulong(1), ii_ )
    ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput(1, ctypes.pointer(x), ctypes.sizeof(x))

# directx scan codes http://www.gamespp.com/directx/directInputKeyboardScanCodes.html
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while (True):
        PressKey(0x11)
        time.sleep(1)
        ReleaseKey(0x11)
        time.sleep(1)
```

and then performing the action...

```
from GameScreen import game_screen, countdown
from Actions import PressKey, ReleaseKey, w
import time


countdown()

print("forward")
PressKey(w)
time.sleep(3)
PressKey(w)
```

I ran this trial code on GTA V and the player didn't move an inch. I then tried this code on GTA Vice City and one another game, and the player took forward steps indefinitely (because of the code, but at least it worked there.) I don't understand how does the same code runs in one game but not in another?
Save me.
How do I run this on GTA V!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution :
Run the editor (in my case, PyCharm) with admin privileges and you're good to go!