# Simulate a combination of Python keypresses, for controlling a game

Tags: python, keypress, simulate, sendinput

I am trying to figure out how to send not one, but a *combination* of python keypresses to a game. For example, let's say I want to use the SHIFT or CTRL modifier, in combination with another key. How would I accomplish this?

There are answers on how to do this for a single keypress, but not a combination. Here is an example of a single keypress solution:

[Simulate Python keypresses for controlling a game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489013/simulate-python-keypresses-for-controlling-a-game)

Comment: the linked question has both press and release functions, so I guess you can press several keys before releasing them, no?

Comment: Thank you, @njzk2! Sending two separate PressKey and ReleaseKey calls, worked like a charm.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simulate Python keypresses for controlling a game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489013/simulate-python-keypresses-for-controlling-a-game)